# How do I go back to previous commit and copy my older files to a new folder

Tags: git

I am currently working on a project and I used GIT to keep track on my files. Now I've change my files so much and I want to copy the original file to my current working directory to compare them. Is there a way that I can do this? Thank you very much if anyone can help!

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to compare a file over different commits, do:

```
git diff <hash> -- <filename>
```

where `<hash>` is the hash of the commit you want to compare. (use `git log` to list commits and see their hash)

Answer (score 0):

To go back to the previous commit

```
git checkout HEAD~1
```

If you want to go back to another commit in the history, you can use `git log` to list the commits, chose the one you want, copy the hash and then

```
git checkout hash_of_your_commit
```

Then just use `cp` to copy your files

Comment: Do I use cp in terminal with the file name after it to copy?

Comment: `cp -r * path_of_your_new_directory` you'll copy all the files and folders this way